# Not able to show more than three custom ribbon button in officejs Desktop Version only

Tags: office-js

Trying to add more than three custom ribbon button which are working in Excel Online version but not showing in Desktop version in Officejs. Only two buttons are displaying if add more button in Desktop version.

Ribbon command button with Action type as Execute Function configured in Manifest file as per git-hub references.

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Button1Id1">                 
    <!--some code here-->
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <!--The name of the function must exist on the FunctionFile DOM. You can put this in a different JS file and then load it on the FunctionFile -->
        <FunctionName>ODSampleData.ODataUX.getButton</FunctionName>
    </Action>
</Control>

<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Button2Id1">
    <!--some code here-->
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>ODSampleData.ODataUX.saveButton</FunctionName>
    </Action>`enter code here`
</Control>

<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Button3Id1">
    <!--some code here-->                  
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>ODSampleData.ODataUX.saveButton</FunctionName>
    </Action>
</Control>
```

Expected Result : Custom Ribbon Button should show in Desktop Version also irrespective of how many getting added.

Actual Result : When trying to add more Custom Ribbon button default two buttons are showing in Desktop Version. Rest are not showing.

Comment: i am using two ShowTaskPane and two ExecuteFunction Action in Manifest. In Excel Online able to view all controls but in Desktop it is showing only two controls.

Comment: Hi Team, Any updates?

Comment: Able to resolve the issues by changing Manifest file hence closing the issue.